How to use shm_open() with a Unique Filename (or alternatives)
I am writing a set of programs on Linux that use shared memory.  Currently I call shm_open() with a predetermined name for the shared memory.  This works fine as I currently only have one set of processes running.  If I want to have multiple, independent, set running I will need to have a unique filename per set.
Ideally I'm looking for something like mkstemp() or mkostemp(), but that works like shm_open().
If that's not something that exists, the two potential options I see are:

Generate a "unique" filename, potentially based on the executable name and the process ID and use that in the call to shm_open().  Is there a way to get this to fail if the shared memory "file" already exists?
Use mkostemp() and then mmap() that file. Is there any real drawback to doing this?  On Linux at least shm_open() seems to not have a physical backing file. Is it such a big deal to have on?


seems to not have a physical backing file But what about /dev/shm? It's even in the man page https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/shm_open.3.html :       The POSIX shared memory object implementation on Linux makes use        of a dedicated tmpfs(5) filesystem that is normally mounted under        /dev/shm.

@KamilCuk but is not /dev/shm typically a tmpfs file system residing in RAM?  Maybe a more explicit way of asking is should I care about finding a way that is not back by a physical disk based file or a way to prefer RAM based files.

@KamilCuk Maybe I misunderstood your comment, and I think it is because I was not clear in my question.  Am I right in thinking I should prefer to use shm_open() so that my shared memory lives on a tmpfs rather? Or, for the most part would it not matter if I create in, say, /tmp?  I guess I DO want to use shm_open(), but is there a way to guarantee a unique filename?

is not /dev/shm typically a tmpfs file system residing in RAM? It is. Why is it a question? should I care I do not understand a qusetion. Shared memory is in memory. If you open a file on disc, it is a shared... file, not memory. I should prefer to use shm_open() Do you want to be POSIX portable? All shm_open does is just open("/dev/shm/something") https://github.com/lattera/glibc/blob/master/sysdeps/posix/shm_open.c#L44 , https://github.com/lattera/glibc/blob/master/sysdeps/posix/shm-directory.h#L42 . Just open a file in /dev/shm yourself. If /tmp/ is tmpfs, then you can use it too.

I feel kind of dumb about this, but it looks like shm_open() does do exactly what I want.  I guess I wasn't clear.  If I use O_EXCL with O_CREAT I get the behavior I desire.
